# The screen print is confusing ?

Tags: c, fflush

my code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main( int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%s", argv[0]);
    system("pwd");
}
```

The output is:

```
[river@localhost studio]$ ./a.out 
/home/river/Desktop/studio
./a.out[river@localhost studio]$
```

It seems that system("pwd") print first , then print argv[0] . why?
If I add a statement like following :

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void main( int argc, char** argv) {
        printf("%s", argv[0]);
        fflush(stdout);
        system("pwd");
    }
```

The output is :

```
[river@localhost studio]$ ./a.out 
./a.out/home/river/Desktop/studio
```

It work normally, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` call only puts the output in a buffer. For the buffer to actually be written it needs to be *flushed*. Output is automatically flushed when you print a newline, so if you replace the format-string in `printf` with this: `"%s\n"` it should work without the call to `fflush`.

Comment: ... and calling "system" does not flush the output stream or even use the output stream - the command invoked by "system" writes directly and immediately to the console, then the buffer is flushed when the program ends, and the line you printfed is shown.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to 'fix' it:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
```

The thing is that stdout is linebuffered by default.

See:

- setbuf(), setvbuf()
- [stdbuf](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html)